# Почему я не могу удалить react?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native

Удаляю react а он все равно есть в системе?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вместо `global` - `-g`

Comment: Так этож вроде тоже самое. Но все равно не помогает

Comment: Не одно и то же, `global` - "название пакета", `-g` - ключ. Удаляйте не react-native, а `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`

Comment: Сделал. Все равно не удалился

Comment: p to date in 0.054s

Comment: Попробуйте заново установить и после этого удалить `npm i -g react-native-cli` `npm uninstall react-native-cli -g`

Comment: MacBook-Air-Ivan:Documents ivansinevich$ npm i -g react-native-cli
/Users/ivansinevich/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/react-native -> /Users/ivansinevich/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
+ react-native-cli@2.0.1
added 41 packages in 6.182s
MacBook-Air-Ivan:Documents ivansinevich$ npm uninstall react-native-cli -g
removed 41 packages in 0.553s
MacBook-Air-Ivan:Documents ivansinevich$ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory
MacBook-Air-Ivan:Documents ivansinevich$

Comment: Тоже самое. Все равно работает react-native -v

Comment: В проекте не установлен пакет?

Comment: `npm ls -g --depth=0` - проверьте какие пакеты у вас стоят глобально.

Comment: Я из проекта удалаю. Там тоже самое

Comment: MacBook-Air-Ivan:parking ivansinevich$ npm ls -g --depth=0
/Users/ivansinevich/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/lib
└── npm@5.6.0

Comment: Тогда такое комбо: `npm uninstall react-native-cli --save-dev` `npm -g uninstall react-native-cli --save`

Comment: Все равно работает команда)

Comment: я иссяк, вызывайте экзорциста ... xDDD И попутно разместите краткое описание того, что мы тут проделали в тело вопроса для следующих соискателей, что бы не повторяться ...

Comment: )))))))))))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал обновить версию node до последней версии *(судя по комментам у вас 8.11.1)*. Только что проверил на своей машине - [согласно документации](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/uninstalling-global-packages), всё должно удаляться командой `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`

[image: Скриншот]

P.S. Установлен ли у вас create-react-native-app? Попробуйте предварительно удалить его.

P.P.S. Ну и совет из области экзорцизма - попробуйте сделать рестарт системы и удалить снова...